# package.json "abc-domains": "latest", not working

Tags: typescript, npm, vuejs2, package.json

**Scenario**

There is a package that I created. Let's say the package name is `abc-domains`.
In the `package.json` file of my project the following is written:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "@company/abc-domains": "latest",
  ...
}
...
```

When running the command `npm outdated` on the project it shows the following output:

```
Package                           Current  Wanted  Latest  Location                                       Depended by 
@company/abc-domains              0.1.47   0.1.49  0.1.49  node_modules/@company/abc-domains              ProjectName
```

**Problem**

When executing the command `npm i` on the project, it will not update the latest changes to the `node_modules`. Why is that?
Only when I specifically run `npm i abc-domains@latest` or just `npm i abc-domains`, then it DOES install the version `0.1.49` and it also updates `latest` to `^0.1.49` in the `package.json`.

Comment: Do you have a lock file? See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @jonrsharpe I was pointed out on the `package-lock.json` file.

This was indeed the troublemaker, because when I removed the file and then ran `npm i` again, it worked as expected! (and the `package-lock.json` file was updated also to `"latest"`).

But just to get rid of this problem in the future and other annoying issues I encoutered before with the `package-lock.json` file, I added the following line to my `.npmrc` file to resolve this once and forever:

```
package-lock=false
```